# I'm always reimplementing observer/subject code in Java. Is there a better option?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm always writing observer/subject interfaces in a particular Java project, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Registers the receiver to the dispatcher. 
 * When data arrives that the receiver can process, 
 * it will be passed to the receiver.
 * ...
 */
void addReceiver(IDataReceiver receiver);

/**
 * @return
 *      True, if the receiver has been registered, false otherwise.
 * ...
 */
boolean hasReceiver(IDataReceiver receiver);

...
```

When a class implements these interfaces, I have to implement the code, test it, debug it, etc. It feels so futile to keep reimplementing such similar logic. Is there *any* better option in Java?

Comment: We need a bit more context than this.  Can you post some more example code, perhaps one of your implementations?

Comment: My problem essentially comes down to implementing callback functions in Java. It feels incredibly clumsy to keep re-writing event handling code. I'm not sure how more code could be of use :S

Comment: It would tell us why you are using the callback functions in the first place, and perhaps suggest to us a better way that does not involve callback functions, or show us why we should tell you that callback functions are the best way (if that is, indeed, the case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some abstractions in the Java API for the `Observer Pattern`. For example the `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`. In combination with the `java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport` it's possible to abstract your problem a little bit.

This example is from the Oracle Doc of Java:

```
public class MyBean {
 private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

 public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
     this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }

 public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
     this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }

 private String value;

 public String getValue() {
     return this.value;
 }

 public void setValue(String newValue) {
     String oldValue = this.value;
     this.value = newValue;
     this.pcs.firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, newValue);
 }

 [...]
}
```

With the `String` in `firePropertyChange` you can define, which property is changed. Of course, because of the use of the `String` the type safety is lost.

You won't get rid of this part before Java8:

```
 private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

 public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
     this.pcs.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }

 public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
     this.pcs.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }
```

The only possibility is, to inherit it from an abstract base class. But if you do that, you can not have another base class.

Since Java8 you can define default methods in interfaces. You can define an interface like that:

```
public interface Listenable {
    PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport ();

    default void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        getPropertyChangeSupport ().addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    default void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        getPropertyChangeSupport ().removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

The `getter` is needed, because Interfaces can't have members directly.

Then it should be possible to avoid a little bit more boilerplate code:

```
public class MyBean implements Listenable {
 private final PropertyChangeSupport pcs = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
 @Override     
 public PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport () {
     return pcs;
 }

 private String value;

 public String getValue() {
     return this.value;
 }

 public void setValue(String newValue) {
     String oldValue = this.value;
     this.value = newValue;
     this.pcs.firePropertyChange("value", oldValue, newValue);
 }

 [...]
}
```

Well, I don't see a possibility in Java, to do it completely without boilerplate code.

Comment: I'm excited for Java8, then. Default methods look like mixins that are available in Scala, which effectively remove the need for the boilerplate. In the meantime... boilerplate it is. T_T

Comment: Yes, default methods are some like mixins in Scala. 

Java8 is released since March 2014, you don't have to wait ;-)